# Jquery - access global array inside each loop

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops, each

How can I access globally declared array inside my each loop? When I try, it returns undefined. I tried adding `window.` prefix

```
var array = [];

$( document ).scroll(function() {

    console.log(array);
    //returns array contents

    $('div').each(function(){

        console.log(array);
        //returns undefined


   });
});
```

Comment: not unless you have a `var array` in the each callback method

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/L56nzwwx/2/ & http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/L56nzwwx/3/

Comment: I could not replicate this issue, see the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/Pontual/ysob5mx3/

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = [1,54,2];
console.log(array);

$(array).each(function(index,value){

  console.log(value);
});
```